# How to implement animation when Image source changed?

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin.forms and want to start an animation when the image source are changed.

```
           <ListView >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Image Source="{Binding FavoriteImage}" x:Name="favoriteImage">
                                 <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                     TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference CurrentPage},Path=BindingContext.ClickLikedCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                 </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

The image source is bind to an variable in the ViewModel and will be changed if user click the image and get a successful response from server. Then the new Image will be shown with some custom animation, so where can I trigger this animation since the image source changed?
I have read the "Behavior" and "Trigger" tutorial online, It seems it could trigger an animation by an event, but Image class has not such an "SourceChanged" event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `OnPropertyChanged` method:

```
public class ExImage : Image
{
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == nameof(Source))
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await this.ScaleTo(1.2);
                await this.ScaleTo(1);
            });
    }
}
```