# Xamarin Forms - animate a change of image source with C#

Tags: c#, image, animation, xamarin.forms

I'm looking to see if there is a way to make a change if image source appear as if it is sliding in, much like a carousel.

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729734/how-to-implement-animation-when-image-source-changed) but here the answer suggests a simple animation, not a slide in effect, my set-up is similar to the above mention post in that my image source is bound to a variable in a view model.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Whats wrong with using a simple animation? Just call `TranslateTo` to move the image, and maybe also use `FadeTo` to let it (dis)appear? https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-animations-with-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks, I think I may be able to get what I want with a combination of this and Easing

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck :)

Comment: @Johannes good idea. Based on it, I gave an answer with this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The defaults animation features Xamarin.Forms provides is enough to achieve what you want.

Following the @Johannes's idea,  for example, you can have a nice animation.

Here's an implementation:

**XAML**

```
<Image x:Name="image" 
       Source="Icon"
       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"
        Text="Animate"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uint transitionTime = 600;
    double displacement = image.Width;

    await Task.WhenAll(
        image.FadeTo(0, transitionTime, Easing.Linear),
        image.TranslateTo(-displacement, image.Y, transitionTime, Easing.CubicInOut));

    // Changes image source.
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("Icon");

    await image.TranslateTo(displacement, 0, 0);
    await Task.WhenAll(
        image.FadeTo(1, transitionTime, Easing.Linear),
        image.TranslateTo(0, image.Y, transitionTime, Easing.CubicInOut));
}
```

**Result**

[image]

I hope it helps.