# How can I have a smoother transition for images with MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I am using MAUI with C# for a short time, and I try to update images like clicked buttons, or make some animations like this :

```
Image newComponent = (Image)component; // component is a VisualElement component
newComponent.Source = ImagesReferences.Instance.someImage[index];
```

But I have a problem, It looks like the image first disappear for a very short time and then the proper image appears. It looks weird, and with animations It is worse, images are doing some flickering.

My references are called this way :
`public string value = "file.png";`

I tried to call my image inside an ImageSource like this : `ImageSource someImage= ImageSource.FromFile("file.png");`

I also found some documentation which recommands to use 'ImageSourcePartLoader', but also didn't worked.

Finally, I found some changes from a git user, supposed to correct this specific case for like, a year ago, and once again, seems like It doesn't work, 'cause I'm here.

Help appreciated, I am not a big Stack Overflow user so If there is anything I can do to help (question I forgot to answer right there)

EDIT : my code for animation, inside my instance on ImagesReferences, there is a ImageSource list :

```
private async Task AnimateImage(bool isAnimationUp, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        ImageAnimatedCover.Source = ImagesReferences.Instance.animationCover[currentImageIndex];

        await Task.Delay(80);

        if (isAnimationUp && currentImageIndex < ImagesReferences.Instance.animationCover.Count - 1)
        {
            currentImageIndex++;
            await AnimateImage(isAnimationUp, cancellationToken);
        }
        else if (currentImageIndex >= 1 && !isAnimationUp)
        {
            currentImageIndex--;
            await AnimateImage(isAnimationUp, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Animation annulée");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using for animation and the gif of your displayed animation?

Comment: Why is there a `await Task.Delay(80);` in your code?

Comment: Because I need to change my image at this rate, my problem is for all images, animations and static images. it's when I set a source to my image

Comment: @AlexisBrouard 1. May I know on what platform you want to have a smoother transition for images with MAUI? 2.I can't reproduce the issue, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and add it to your post! 3. Similarly, you can refer to [a nice animation of image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50412638).